# ubuntu 22.04 on Dell XPS 17 9730 (2023): Wired earbuds - speakers switching not working properly automatically or manually

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, headphones, speakers

I have ubuntu 22.04 on Dell XPS 17 9730 (2023).

Output of `uname -a` is:

```
Linux laptop-name 5.19.0-32-generic #33~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jan 30 17:03:34 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It is less than 6 months old. I was using bluetooth earphones until recently, which worked fine. With these dying, I bought cheaper wired earbuds, expecting this to be a simpler solution. No charging, no connecting every time, no choosing devices.

I am experiencing the following behavior:

1. If sound is coming from the speakers, plugging in the earbuds **at best** has no effect. At worst, output **sound starts to go on and off fast**! If I keep the windows button pressed, this stops and sound goes back to normal.
2. Sometimes, if the laptop comes out of hibernation, the on-and-off sound behavior does not occur. I then have to **manually** switch to headphones both in the pulseaudio control and the system settings sound control. In fact this seems to happen alternatively between hibernation events.

And to think that in more than 20 years of using Linux, wired earphones were always automatically detected and speakers muted (and vice versa) leaves me speechless.

I think by now I've seen all possibly related threads on similar issues. No solution works. There is no mute option on ALSA. I uninstalled pulseaudio only to have to reinstall it again. And so on.

Reinstalling any version of the operating system is absolutely not an option. I have tons of newly installed software and I don't have the time for this sort of thing.